# ulimit -s not working on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mac-osx, configuration, process, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to raise the upper level of user processes on my machine. `ulimit -s` doesn't seem to do a thing:

[image]

I've also tried `launchctl limit` with the same results. Don't know what else to do :S

Answer (score 0):

Never tried setting this for a user before, but I'd venture a guess to try `sudo -u pfernand-md ulimit -s 1024`

Comment: Nope this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this link will help:

http://notfornoone.com/2010/11/snow-leopard-10-6-5-and-apachectl/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you **can't raise** a **hard** limit after you've already set it once.

I had to remove the original `ulimit -s 128` that was in one of my config files, specifically `/etc/launchd`